# Inserting a word within a given string

Tags: input

I want the user to input a phrase such as "Python" and have the program put the word "test" in the middle.... So it would print "pyttesthon".

After I input the phrase however, I am not sure which function to use.

Comment: Do you know what language you are using? The proper language tag is probably relevant for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate strings like so:

```
stringToInsert = "test"
oldString = "Python"
newString = oldString[0:len(oldString)/2] + stringToInsert + oldString[len(oldString)/2:]
```